# Android problem related OnItemClickListener of ListView

Tags: android, listview, imageview, onitemclicklistener

I have a ListView in my layout. Here is the layout for list item.

**shopitem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:mode="twoLine"> 
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="44dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
            android:layout_alignRight="@android:id/text1"
            android:src="@drawable/btnplaypreview"/>            
</TwoLineListItem>
```

Now I want to set some change of image in `playBtn` OnItemClickListener. For that I am using the following code.

```
ListView shopActivityListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.shopActivityListView);
shopActivityListView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
shopActivityListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.shopitem, trackArr[1]));

shopActivityListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View vItem, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView playBtn = (ImageView) vItem.findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
    playBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.eq12);
}                
});
```

But nothing is happening on itemclick. I have checked that `onItemClick` method is executing without any exception. But nothing is changing. What is the problem in my code?

Comment: TwoLineListItem is a linearlayout extension? Try to add `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: I have tried that. No change.

Comment: Invalidate your listview after  playBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.eq12);.

Comment: I add shopActivityListView.invalidate() after playBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.eq12), but no change.

Comment: Anyone can give me the proper answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image in any item of `Listview` cannot change directly as it is controlled by Adapter. Only `getView()` method of the adapter can set any view in the items.
Therefore, in `onItemClick` method, we have to set a `position` specific flag and then call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` for the adapter. Moreover, a custom adapter is needed, where we have to define the getView() method so that we have set the image depending on the above `position` specific flag.

Comment: Can you give an example please